# sorting text lines Google Apps Script

Tags: sorting, text, google-apps-script

Sorry for this extreme beginner question. I have a string variable originaltext containing some multiline text. I can convert  it into an array of lines like so:

`lines = originaltext.split("\n");`

But I need help sorting this array. This DOES NOT work:

`lines.sort;`

The array remains unsorted.

---

And an associated question. Assuming I can sort my array somehow, how do I then convert it back to a single variable with no separators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only issue is a small one - `sort` is actually a method, so you need to call `lines.sort()`. In order to join the elements together, you can use the `join()` method:

```
var originaltext = "This\n\is\na\nline";
lines = originaltext.split("\n");
lines.sort();
joined = lines.join("");
```

Comment: @user1770020 Awesome, happy it helps (and welcome to SO:) ). When one of your questions gets answered, you can accept the answer to effectively close the loop. Good luck with everything!